# SQL invoice three tables into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

**Hello,**

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `invoice` (`id`) VALUES
(1), 
(2), 
(3);

CREATE TABLE `invoice_deduction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoiceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deductionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (`invoiceId`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`deductionId`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `invoice_deduction` (`id`, `invoiceId`, `deductionId`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1),
(2, 3, 1),
(3, 3, 2);

CREATE TABLE `invoice_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoiceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (`invoiceId`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `invoice_item` (`id`, `invoiceId`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 2),
(6, 3),
(7, 3),
(8, 3);
```

**For example:**

- The first invoice contains 3 items (total: 3 items)
- The second invoice contains 3 items from first invoice (deduction) and 2 new items (total: 5 items)
- The third invoice contains 3 items from first invoice (deduction), 2 items from second invoice (deduction) and 3 new items (total: 8 items)

So I want to have a query with this result:

```
id | count of items (with deductions)
3  | 8
2  | 5
1  | 3
```

I start with this query:

```
SELECT 
    i.id, COUNT(*) as countItems
FROM
    invoice i JOIN invoice_item it ON i.id = it.invoiceId
GROUP BY
    it.invoiceId
ORDER BY 
    countItems
DESC
```

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Specify MySQL version. Provide DDLs without `...` (simply skip unnesessary fields), some sample data and desured result for it (the best way - create a fiddle).

Comment: 10.0.38-MariaDB

Comment: Oops... CTE and window functions are not available. So stored procedure with temporary table seems to be the best option.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (no images.) And read [mcve].

Comment: Does your data is: single chain? single tree? a lot of trees?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "The second invoice (with deduction) contains 4 items from first invoice and 3 new items."? The language suggest that two invoices share some of the same invoice items and a many-to-many relationship exists between invoices and invoice items requiring a join table that your schema does not support.

Comment: I have edited my post, hopefully it is easier to understand. And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT i.id, COUNT(*) as countItems,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY it.id)
FROM invoice i JOIN
     invoice_item it
     ON i.id = it.invoiceId
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY countItems;
```

I have no idea why you are using a `LEFT JOIN`.  I don't know why you would have `invoiceId` values that do not match a valid invoice.  So I switched it to an inner join.

Comment: OP have a tree, so recursive CTE needed.